# Is this a z-index issue?

Tags: menu, push, z-index, multi-level

I have a menu (this is the menu I'm using with a few modifications: http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/) that floats over an image that is linked. Whenever a link is click that is in front of the image, both links are activated.

I've tried added a higher z-index to the menu wrapper, but still not working. Thoughts?

Here is a screen cap of the problem:
http://tinypic.com/r/znoeh2/8

I know the obviously answer is to make the image not clickable, which I will change but I'm concerned this could cause problems somewhere else on the site.